# applying a function for cell elements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have neighh1 that is 1 by 10 cell

neighh1 =

Columns 1 through 6

```
[5x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [7x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [5x1 double]
```

Columns 7 through 10

```
[4x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [4x1 double]
```

I want to take two cells of neighh1 , for example neighh1{1} & neighh1{3}

neighh1{1}=

2
 4
 7
 8
10

neighh1{3}=

5
 6
 9

I have the matrix N that is a 2-dimentional array that contains 0 & 1,
Then I want to check if N(i,j) == 1 or not . Where i & j are the elements of neighh1{1} & neighh1{3}
so if N(4,7)== 1 I want to save 4 & 7 in a new matrix

Comment: Can you give an example of the function you'd like to apply? What have you tried so far?

Comment: take a look at an inbuilt function `cellfun` http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html

Comment: actully it is not a function in MATLAB, the function is N where N is a 2-dimentional array that contains 0 & 1, so I want to check if  N(i,j) == 1 or not . Where i & j are the elements of neighh1{1} & neighh1{3}

Comment: That's not what you asked for in your question. Can you please update the question with this new information as well as an example, and *format it* so that it doesn't look like such a mess. Thanks!

Comment: Why `N(4,7)`? Aren't you taking the first index from `neighh1{1}` and the second index from `neighh1{3}`? Your question is unclear

Comment: because neighh1{1} & neighh1{3} are vectors that I want to check N(i,j) where i & j are the elements of neighh1{1} &neighh1{3}. 4 and 7 are just examples to illustrate the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments you are simply looking for a way to access the contents of a cell.

I think you are looking for something like  this:

```
for t=1:numel(neighh1{1})
  for k = 1:numel(neigh1{3})
    N(neighh1{1}(t),neigh1{3}(k))
  end
end
```

---

If you want to add the values to a matrix directly in the loop, you could do this:

```
M=[];
for t=1:numel(neighh1{1})
  for k = 1:numel(neigh1{3})
      x = neighh1{1}(t);
      y = neigh1{3}(k);
    if N(x,y)
      M(end+1,:) = [x y];
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I did that, my new question would be how to save the results. For example:if N(4,7)== 1 ;I want to save 4 & 7 in a new matrix,  How I could do such thing?

Comment: @user3685062 How about: `M=[]; M(end+1,:)=[4 7]` , If you know how many results need to be stored you can preallocate `M` at the right size for an increase in efficiency.

Comment: but this special case when you access specific elements in neighh1 not a general one that would be inside the loop .

Comment: @user3685062 It is definitely possible to do this in the loop, check my expanded answer.

Comment: this code is working perfectly,Thanks! I have now another issue. Now I want to do the same thing but not just for neighh1{1} and neighh1{3}, I want to access different cells in neighh1 in each iteration. For example: I want to access neighh1{1}&neighh1{3} in the first iteration , then I want to access neighh1{3}&neighh1{8} in the second iteration . Given that the number of iteration is variable based on my design. Then for each iteration I want to save the result. How could I do such thing

Comment: @user3685062 That is quite a different question. Please try it yourself (think and search online), if you still remain stuck consider asking a new question here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to index `N` with all combinations of the two vectors contained in the two cells:

```
[ii jj] = ndgrid(neighh1{1}, neighh1{3}.')
result = N(sub2ind(size(N), ii,jj));
```

See [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) and [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is possible, easiest if you wanted to apply it for all elements, though. The trick is, you use a subset of that cell and apply the function to all elements of that via `cellfun`

```
cellfun(@length, neighh([1, 3]))
```

It returns the Vector `[5, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = {[1:4].',[1:3].',[4:7].',[1:7].'}
A = 
    [4x1 double]    [3x1 double]    [4x1 double]    [7x1 double]
```

To execute a function on all elements, you can use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) straight forward like this:

```
B = cellfun(@sin, A, 'uni', 0);
```

You can after this use the cells you want using regular indexing.

If you really want to execute a function *only* on cells 2 and 3, you may do:

```
B = cellfun(@sin, A([2, 3]), 'uni', 0);
```